# Create groupPolicyDefinitionValue

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I want to Create a DefinitionValue based on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-grouppolicy-grouppolicydefinitionvalue-create?view=graph-rest-beta).

But this doesn't work:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/groupPolicyConfigurations/{groupPolicyConfigurationID}/definitionValues](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/groupPolicyConfigurations/%7BgroupPolicyConfigurationID%7D/definitionValues)

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.groupPolicyDefinitionValue",
    "enabled": true,
    "configurationType": "policy",
    "definition@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/groupPolicyDefinitions('{groupPolicyDefinitionID}')"
}
```

Does anyone know, how I'm able to create a Definition Value?

Edit:
Thats the Error I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "{  \"_version\": 3,  \"Message\": \"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: dae9a903-29fe-6dd7-bb27-e02f375f816a - Url: https://fef.msub06.manage.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/GroupPolicyAdminService/b15c97ad-ffff-4805-0302-032414203983/deviceManagement/groupPolicyConfigurations%28%276c39baa2-f47a-4d9f-a7cb-327ea6b60fc0%27%29/definitionValues?api-version=5018-11-06\",  \"CustomApiErrorPhrase\": \"\",  \"RetryAfter\": null,  \"ErrorSourceService\": \"\",  \"HttpHeaders\": \"{}\"}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-03-28T08:26:26",
            "request-id": "0a9df5c8-ec3f-42e3-be57-0db8d193672a",
            "client-request-id": "dae9a903-29fe-6dd7-bb27-e02f375f816a"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the exception or any error what do you receive?